# Trying to draw a function curve with Hobby

Tags: tikz-pgf, hobby

I use to draw function curves with Bezier, when I want them to fit multiple conditions, i.e. tangent lines, maximum and minimum, and the curve going through chosen points. This is to be used with my students when  working on functions properties.
I assumed that I could do this more easily with `hobby` library, but I can't get to something even acceptable, so I need your help.
Here are the intended curve (in orange) and the result with Hobby (in dashed purple).
[image: Hobby ugly curve]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
    \tikzset{tangent/.style={in angle ={(180+#1)},
            Hobby finish,
            designated Hobby path=next,
            out angle=#1}}
    \tikzset{axe/.style={line width=1pt,-{Latex[length=4mm,width=2mm]}}}
    \tikzset{courbe/.style={line width=1.5pt,dashed, purple}}
    \draw[cyan,very thin] (-7,-4) grid (6,4);
    \draw[axe] (-7,0) -- (6,0);
    \draw[axe] (0,-4) -- (0,4);

    % Bezier curve
    
        % points
    \coordinate (p1) at (-7,-4);
    \coordinate (p2) at (-5,0);
    \coordinate (p3) at (-3,2);
    \coordinate (p4) at (0,-3);
    \coordinate (p5) at (1,-1);
    \coordinate (p6) at (2,-4);
    \coordinate (p7) at (4,.5);
    \coordinate (p8) at (6,3);
    
        % control points
    \coordinate (b1) at (-6,-3.5);
    \coordinate (a2) at (-6.5,0);
    \coordinate (b2) at (-4,0); 
    \coordinate (a3) at (-4,2);
    \coordinate (b3) at (-1.9,2);
    \coordinate (a4) at (-0.4,-3);
    \coordinate (b4) at (.5,-3);
    \coordinate (a5) at (0.5,-1);
    \coordinate (b5) at (1.5,-1);
    \coordinate (a6) at (1.5,-4);
    \coordinate (b6) at (2.5,-4);
    \coordinate (a7) at (3,0.5);
    \coordinate (b7) at (4.5,.5);
    \coordinate (a8) at (5.5,1);

        % curve 
    \draw[line width=1.5pt, orange]
        (p1) .. controls (b1) and (a2) .. (p2)
        (p2) .. controls (b2) and (a3) .. (p3)
        (p3) .. controls (b3) and (a4) .. (p4)
        (p4) .. controls (b4) and (a5) .. (p5)
        (p5) .. controls (b5) and (a6) .. (p6)      
        (p6) .. controls (b6) and (a7) .. (p7)  
        (p7) .. controls (b7) and (a8) .. (p8)      
        ;   
        
    % Hobby curve
    
    \draw[courbe] 
        ([tangent=25]-7,-4) ..
        ([tangent=0]-5,0) ..
        ([tangent=0]-3,2) ..
        ([tangent=0]0,-3) ..
        ([tangent=0]1,-1) ..
        ([tangent=0]2,-4) ..
        ([tangent=0]4,.5) ..
        ([tangent=75]6,3);
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I tried to add some tension with `[tension=0.5]` for example, and even other properties but can't see where it leads.

Comment: The constraint of making a curve that is suitable for a function doesn't fit well with Hobby's algorithm as the optimisation in the algorithm doesn't have preferred directions so will happily make a curve seemingly double back on itself.  I've often wondered if there's a modification that would work for this sort of situation but I've not come up with anything as yet.  So I would not recommend using hobby for this.

Comment: Yeah what @AndrewStacey said. But, if you want a work around just specify more points around the points where the curve is not behaving as desired.  That is, increase the density of the given points near the points of any local max and min.  With this I have been able to achived the desired results and let hobby do the rest.

Comment: Thanks to you both. I don't find it relevant to add too much points, since I'm looking for an easier method. I'll stick with my well known Bezier curve, then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you mainly specify the local extrema, you can work with the `to` syntax and

```
\draw[in=180,out=0] .... ;
```

You can still specify the slopes at specific points by locally adjusting the `in` and `out` keys. You only need to make sure that a given `in` value and the subsequent `out` value differ by `180`. Additional fine tuning can be achieved by playing with the `looseness`, or even `out looseness` and `in looseness`. They indicate how far the control points are away from the first and last point of the sequence, while the `in` and `out` keys set the angles of these control points. The result of my very first attempt is the cyan-blue curve.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
    \tikzset{tangent/.style={in angle ={(180+#1)},
            Hobby finish,
            designated Hobby path=next,
            out angle=#1}}
    \tikzset{axe/.style={line width=1pt,-{Latex[length=4mm,width=2mm]}}}
    \tikzset{courbe/.style={line width=1.5pt,dashed, purple}}
    \draw[cyan,very thin] (-7,-4) grid (6,4);
    \draw[axe] (-7,0) -- (6,0);
    \draw[axe] (0,-4) -- (0,4);

    % Bezier curve
    
        % points
    \coordinate (p1) at (-7,-4);
    \coordinate (p2) at (-5,0);
    \coordinate (p3) at (-3,2);
    \coordinate (p4) at (0,-3);
    \coordinate (p5) at (1,-1);
    \coordinate (p6) at (2,-4);
    \coordinate (p7) at (4,.5);
    \coordinate (p8) at (6,3);
    
        % control points
    \coordinate (b1) at (-6,-3.5);
    \coordinate (a2) at (-6.5,0);
    \coordinate (b2) at (-4,0); 
    \coordinate (a3) at (-4,2);
    \coordinate (b3) at (-1.9,2);
    \coordinate (a4) at (-0.4,-3);
    \coordinate (b4) at (.5,-3);
    \coordinate (a5) at (0.5,-1);
    \coordinate (b5) at (1.5,-1);
    \coordinate (a6) at (1.5,-4);
    \coordinate (b6) at (2.5,-4);
    \coordinate (a7) at (3,0.5);
    \coordinate (b7) at (4.5,.5);
    \coordinate (a8) at (5.5,1);

        % curve 
    \draw[line width=1.5pt, orange]
        (p1) .. controls (b1) and (a2) .. (p2)
        (p2) .. controls (b2) and (a3) .. (p3)
        (p3) .. controls (b3) and (a4) .. (p4)
        (p4) .. controls (b4) and (a5) .. (p5)
        (p5) .. controls (b5) and (a6) .. (p6)      
        (p6) .. controls (b6) and (a7) .. (p7)  
        (p7) .. controls (b7) and (a8) .. (p8)      
        ;   
        
    % Hobby curve
    
    \draw[courbe] 
        ([tangent=25]-7,-4) ..
        ([tangent=0]-5,0) ..
        ([tangent=0]-3,2) ..
        ([tangent=0]0,-3) ..
        ([tangent=0]1,-1) ..
        ([tangent=0]2,-4) ..
        ([tangent=0]4,.5) ..
        ([tangent=75]6,3);

  \draw[blue,double=cyan,thick,in=180,out=0,looseness=0.6] 
        (-7,-4) to[out=25]
        (-5,0) to
        (-3,2) to
        (0,-3) to
        (1,-1) to
        (2,-4) to
        (4,.5) to[in=180+75]
        (6,3);
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Pumuckl. That's a pretty interesting solution to avoid all the control points in this case, even if it's not using the Hobby algorithm.

Comment: @SebGlav Yes, I do not know how to achieve this with the Hobby algorithm, but according to the above comments it may not be trivial (or even feasible). Yet I'd definitely be interested in seeing how this works.